# Set the selected value in select2 multiple using PHP

Tags: php

> How will i set the selected item in select2 multiple ?  i would like to set these option/values as selected by default in a multiple select list and display them to the user where they will be able to updated their data if necessary.

```
<?php
$mytitle  = array(
"867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670");
$test = implode(',', $mytitle);

$query=mysqli_query($link,"select * from inventory where ITEM_CODE_MX='OPP01-3006GRY'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{

$imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
$title = explode(',', $imei);
}
?>
<script>

  $(function () {
    $('#tags').select2();
    function select (event){
      $("#tags").select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: $('#quantitytotransfer').val(),
        formatSelectionTooBig: function (limit) {
          $('#box').show().text('Callback!');
          parseInt($("#quantitytotransfer").val())
          return 'Too many selected elements (' + limit + ')';
        }
      });
    }

    $('#quantitytotransfer').on('keyup', select);

    select()
  });

</script>


<select id="tags" name='title[]' style="width:300px;"  class="form-control select2-offscreen" onchange="getCount()" multiple>
<?php
  foreach ($title as $opt) {
      $sel = '';
    $wew = trim($is);
      if (in_array($opt, $mytitle)) {

      $sel = 'selected="selected" ';
      }
     if (!empty($opt)) {
      echo "<option ' . $sel . ' value='$opt'>$opt</option>";
    }
  }
?>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to select the first option here is the code

```
$sel = "selected";
    foreach ($title as $opt) {
         if (!empty($opt)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $opt . "'" . $sel . ">" . $opt . "</option>";
            $sel = "";
        }
```

Comment: would you please print_r($title) and add it to the question?

Comment: where should i put ? because its not showing the output of print_r

Comment: carlos i used your test array and added it to to answer maybe it helps you check it out

Comment: yeah it showing the array value but not all the value that came from database, :(

Comment: after that code  

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
$imei=$row["IMEI_MX"];
$title = explode(',', $imei);
}

use print_r($title);

Comment: Array ( [0] => 867310020292434 [1] => 867310021548131 [2] => 867310021561670 [3] => 867310021820258 [4] => 867310021561639 [5] => 867310021557470 [6] => 867310020292533 [7] => 865966029842917 [8] => 867310021562058 [9] => 867310021819631 [10] => 867310021814871 [11] => 865966029848658 )

Comment: with this output it should be working fine what are you getting in the selection menu?

Comment: 867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670

Comment: it should be 867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670, 867310021820258, 867310021561639, 867310021557470, 867310020292533, 865966029842917, 867310021562058, 867310021819631, 867310021814871, 865966029848658

Comment: and those 3 should automatically selected when page load

Comment: you mean you are getting only three instead of all of them?

Comment: sadly yes i only get this 3 items

Comment: you sure you used $imei?

Comment: title variable is for overall value that came from database and mytitle is from me that i want automatically selected when i load

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(202) "867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670, 867310021820258, 867310021561639, 867310021557470, 867310020292533, 865966029842917, 867310021562058, 867310021819631, 867310021814871, 865966029848658" [1]=> string(202) "867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670, 867310021820258, 867310021561639, 867310021557470, 867310020292533, 865966029842917, 867310021562058, 867310021819631, 867310021814871, 865966029848658"  " }

Comment: okay i just figured out what you mean ! mytitle after imploding value is not equal to any of title array and it's get's you only three because you only supplied three "867310020292434, 867310021548131, 867310021561670");

Comment: if you want the first value to be selected automatically it's easy

Comment: @CarlosJhonmanlulu here you go if it solved your problem select my answer as the one answered your problem hope it helps

Comment: i want those 3 will automatically selected :(

Comment: or all of the value i will put in mytitle